# De-indexing microsites in Google

Tags: subdomain, search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content, google-index

I need to de-index some content from Google.

We have a main domain `main.example.com` which has listing of E-commerce products. Also, we give this for internal use to companies on their subdomain. Example:

```
company1.example.com
company2.example.com
…
company100.example.com
```

Problem is, Google is detecting the content of our main site as duplicate.

How can this be prevented? I am ok to block crawling of microsites as they are for internal use only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent indexing is to serve the `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP header from all of those subdomains.

You could also add the robots noindex meta tag to all pages, but that only works for HTML documents.

More info: https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks Maximillian. What if I add Disallow in robots.txt? Will that be serving any purpose.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal It often works in practice, but it's not a 100% solution because Google is known to index pages in some cases even if they are disallowed from crawling them. Using the `noindex` tag or header is the way that works 100%.